# How to fix problem of length of Gantt diagram on R?

Tags: r, date, gantt-chart

I have a planning on two years but R is not able to continue the Gantt Diagramme after 1year.
How to say to R to continue the year after?

Comment: Do you think, this question should be asked on SO?

Comment: There are no technical details provided on what you have tried and what you actually need to achieve.